# not able to import ddt in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

```
import unittest

from ddt import  data, unpack
from selenium import webdriver
import ddt

@ddt

class searchddt(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        self.driver.get('https://magento.com/products/magento-commerce')

        @data(("phones",2))
        @unpack
        def test_search(self,search_val,expected_count):
            self.searchfield=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//I[@aria-hidden='true']/self::I")
            self.searchfield.clear()
            self.searchfield.send_keys(search_val)
            self.searchfield.submit()


        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.quit()
    if __name__=='__main__':
        unittest.main(verbosity=2)



FAILED (errors=1)
```

## getting error in importing ddt and code is not executing

> Error
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File `"C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py"`, line `329`, in run
>               testMethod()
>             File `"C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py"`, line 32, in testFailure
>               raise exception
>           ImportError: Failed to import test module: ddt
>           
>               class searchddt(unittest.TestCase):
>           TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>
> ```
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue lies in the way that you are importing needed decorators

```
from ddt import  data, unpack
from selenium import webdriver
import ddt
```

If you look at the last statement, you are importing ddt which is a module, and this is causing the error when decorating the class. You need a decorator - callable that is located inside the ddt module.

I think that the solution would be to import it in the first line like this

```
from ddt import ddt, data, unpack
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: Have you removed `import ddt` from the last line?

Comment: Not sure what going on then. Are you getting the same error or a different one? The following code compiles and runs: https://repl.it/repls/SpottedUnequaledMouflon, maybe you can try it out and tell me what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

The first is covered by the other answer: you need to `from ddt import ddt` rather than `import ddt`.

The second is that your test function is decorated with `@unpack`, so the tuple you pass to `@data` will be unpacked by ddt, creating two function calls: `test_search_1("phones")` and `test_search_2(2)`. This isn't what you want.

You probably want something like:

```
@data([
    {"search_val": "phones", "expected_count": 2},
    {"search_val": "things", "expected_count": 3},
    {"search_val": "stuff", "expected_count": 4},
])
@unpack
def test_search(self, search_val, expected_count):
```

There's a bonus third issue, which is the indentation of your test and tearDown functions, which should not be within setUp.